# why key is used in the tuple ? and what's syntax here

Tags: python

```
def LongestWord(sen):

    nw = ""
    for letter in sen:
      if letter.isalpha() or letter.isnumeric():
        nw += letter
      else :
        nw += " "
    return max(nw.split(),key=len)

print(LongestWord("Hello world"))
```

what is the `key=len` means. `key` is used in `dict` right ? I can't understand the syntax here `max(nw.split(), key=len)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
max(nw.split(),key=len)
```

Here, `max(iterator, default, key=function)`  max function takes 3 arguments first is iterator like list, tuple, or dictonay.

Second parameter is default value to return if the iterator is empty, the second paramter is optional.

third parameter is a key word argument that is `key=function` we have to pass a function that take one parameter and our each value in the iterator is passed to this function so the on the bases of return value of this function our `max()` function gives output to us.

third parameter is also a optional paramter.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that dictionaries contain mappings from keys to values. In this particular case though, `key` is just one of the parameters of the `max` function. It allows the caller to specify a sort function. For more information, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max.

Answer (score 1):

`max` means `maximum`, but what metric's maximum are you trying to find? That's where the `key` comes in. Here, the `key` is `len` (length) that is the you are trying to find the element with the highest length. In case of words you can not simply use greater than or less than, hence you need to specify a `key` with which you determine the pattern. For example:

```
>>> words = ['this','is','an','example']
>>> max(words, key=len)
'example'
```

You can think of the keys as the keys in dictionary, as they key here is `len`, the dict would be like:
`{4: 'this', 2: 'an', 7: 'example'}`
So it will return the value of the highest `key` (`7`), that is `example`.
You can also define custom keys:

```
>>> def vowels(word):
...     '''this returns number of vowels
...        in a word'''
...     v = 'aeiou'
...     ctr = 0
...     for char in word:
...         if char in v:
...             ctr += 1
...     return ctr
>>> words = ['standing','in','a','queue']
>>> max(words, key = vowels)
'queue'
```

The dictionary analogy would be:
`{2:'standing', 1: 'a', 3: 'queue'}`
So the answer will be `queue`

Answer (score 0):

Here `key` is for the method `max()`.
Since this function is to find the longest word in the string, you are trying to find the word with max `length`, hence `key = len`

Example:

`max(111,222,333,444,555,999)  = 999`

`max(111,222,333,444,555,999, key = lambda x:x%3 ) = 111`